# Proving linear independence

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Show that {1,√2} in $\mathbb{R}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$

Here is what I have done and I wanted to see if this was correct:

Let c$_1$+c$_2$√2=0, where c$_1$,c$_2$ $\in$$\mathbb{Q}$
Here we want to show that c$_1$=c$_2$=0.

(Proof by Contradiction)

Suppose at least one of c$_1$ and c$_2$ are nonzero. Let C$_2$ be nonzero.

Then, -c$_1$= c$_2$√2.

And since c$_2$ is non zero, then (-c$_1$)/(c$_2$)=√2

But then this implies √2 is rational, hence contradiction.

Thus c$_2$=0. Now since c$_2$ is 0, then c$_1$+(0)√2=0 and this implies that c$_1$=0 and this shows linear independence.

I am then asked to prove that √3 is not a linear combination of 1 and √2 with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ and to conclude that {1,√2} does not span $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I want to see how I can use what I just proved to show this.

Comment: It's absolutely correct!

Comment: @Mathematician42 Okay, thank you for the feedback. I just added a last part in just now, another question.

Comment: Should be "Suppose at least one of $c_1$ or $c_2$ is nonzero" (not both).

Comment: @Nunya: I missed that, that's correct.

Comment: @Nunya Oh, it cannot be both? How would this change what I have. I would still get the contradiction correct, but then this would give me the other is zero as well?

Comment: You should still be able to arrive at a contradiction. Recall that for linear dependence, at least one of the scalars must be nonzero. So just assume that at least one of $c_1$ or $c_2$ is nonzero. Consider cases. Case 1: $c_1 \neq 0$. Case 2: $c_1 = 0$ but $c_2 \neq 0$.

Comment: @Nunya If I assume my C$_2$ is nonzero could I keep most of my argument or do I still need cases?

Comment: You need to assume $(c_1,c_2)$ is non-zero as a couple. Then you have to consider multiple cases. But if one of them is zero, so is the other, hence $c_1$ and $c_2$ are both non-zero. See also a similar (but different) argument in my answer.

Comment: Your proof is correct, it's just that if you assume that $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are linearly independent, then by definition there exists a non-trivial linear combination of $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ that yields zero. A proiri it could be that $x\cdot 1=0$ or $y\cdot \sqrt{2}=0$, but clearly this is not the case here.

Comment: It's correct now, be sure to look at the answer to the last question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the latter statement you can do exactly the same. Suppose $\sqrt{3}=c_1\cdot 1+c_2\cdot \sqrt{2}$ for $(c_1,c_2)\in \mathbb{Q}^2\setminus\left\{(0,0)\right\}$.

Clearly $c_2\neq 0$, for if it were not, then $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}$. Now $\sqrt{3}-c_2\sqrt{2}=c_1$, taking squares, we get that $$3-2c_2\sqrt{6}+2c_2^2=c_1^2.$$
Rearranging, you find that

$$\sqrt{6}=\frac{c_1^2-2c_2^2-3}{-2c_2}.$$
Thus $\sqrt{6}\in \mathbb{Q}$, but it's not, so again we arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: Question: what at the beginning you are stating neither coefficient is 0?

Comment: I'm not, I'm stating that I assume $(c_1,c_2)\neq (0,0)$, it could still be $(0,1)$ or something similar.

Comment: Oh okay, it is the same argument as above. I have another answer actually now that I understand, but this answer also makes sense to me.

Comment: How does this imply the set does not span R over Q?

Comment: If it spanned $\mathbb{R}$, then $\sqrt{3}$ should be in it, but it's not by the argument above.